# Check for the existence of file in cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm attempting to check for the existence of a file with cordova in ionic  but I keep getting a `NOT_FOUND_ERR` message. If I change `nativeURL` to `fullPath` I get a `ENCODING_ERR`. The official documentation asks for two parameters: path and file. Some examples online show the file name/path as the only parameter. I've tried both versions with no luck.

```
        myFactory.transfer_file(url, download, {}, true, function(state, ob){
            if(state=="success"){
              $cordovaFile.checkFile(ob["nativeURL"]).then(function(result) {
                  console.log('File Success!');
              }, function(err) {                 
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
              });

            }
        });
```

The `file_transfer` function is just a wrapper I've created around `$cordovaFileTransfer.download`

```
  $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
  .then(function(result) {
    callback("success", result);
  }, function(err) {

    callback("fail", err);

  }, function (progress) {
    callback("progress", progress);
  });
```

The transfer works correctly and the file now exists on the file system which I've checked using adb. But it's not found using the `checkFile` function.

I'm not sure what the problem is considering that I'm using the exact path that's being returned on completion of the file transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the two parameter version thats in the [current documentation](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/). The first path parameter should **only** be the basepath. The second should be the remaining path and the filename.

So if you used `cordova.file.dataDirectory+"images/img1.png"` to create the file, the code would be `$cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, "images/img1.png")` to check if it exists.

**Not** `$cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory+"images/", "img1.png")` as I first tried.

Comment: Whats the path to read/see if a file exists in the root www/img folder?